# Installing desktop-experience feature with DSC

Tags: dsc

I'm running into an issue when utilizing DSC to provision a machine. I'm trying to enable the windows feature 'desktop-experience' and then some others.
My configuration looks like this:

```
Configuration Workstation
{
   Node WSTest
   {
      WindowsFeature DesktopExperience
      { 
         Ensure          = "Present" 
         Name            = "Desktop-Experience"
      }
      WindowsFeature RemoteAccess
      {
         Ensure          = "Present"
         Name            = "RemoteAccess"
      }
   }
}
```

Now this works only partially. My LCM is set to RebootNodeIfNeeded = true and will automatically reboot when the Desktop-Experience feature asks for it. It will even state 'A reboot is scheduled to progress further. Configuration will be continued after the reboot.' but after the **two** following, it won't continue with the RemoteAccess feature. This only seems to happen when there's a double reboot involved. A single reboot will work just fine.

It almost seems as though the LCM-scheduled task gets interrupted and therefore doesn't complete the configuration. Has anyone else experienced this behavior? Any solutions?

Comment: probably a stupid question, since i am learning, but i will ask anyway... If you put remote access first, does it work correctly? i know its a "work around" if it works, but just curious...

Comment: I'm late to the party, but for anyone else coming here:  check that `Get-DscLocalConfigurationManager` ActionAfterReboot is set to ContinueConfiguration.